# Set comments at the same indentation level as all forms

Tags: emacs, elisp, indentation

By default, comments get an indentation level which seems rather alien to me.

```
(defun example ()
  just
  some
                ; a comment
  words)
```

How to adjust it so the first semicolon is vertically aligned with the regular Lisp forms?

```
(defun example ()
  just
  some
  ; a comment
  words)
```

What I could find out is that the default mechanism works by aligning the comments to a fixed column (queryable via `M-x comment-set-column`), and that one can modify the `comment-indent-function` variable (setting it to nil partially fixes my problem).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Emacs indents comments in elisp differently depending on the number of semicolons used. If you use two, you should get the indentation you're after:

```
(defun test-single ()
                                        ; A single semicolon
  nil)

(defun test-double ()
  ;; Do two semicolons make a colon ;)
  nil)
```

In addition, three semicolons `;;;` are not re-indented at all. Typically, they are used to mark new major sections in the source file.

Comment: Great! Can I configure Emacs so `;` behaves exactly as `;;`?

Comment: I don't think that you would want to do that. It would make your code indent differently from all other elisp code... Anyway, this is hardcoded into `lisp-indent-line`, so you would have to modify it (perhaps using `defadvice`).

Answer (score 1):

You may customize comment-indent-function

Instead of comment-indent-default use your own function.

Writing a new by replacing in last line `comment-column' by
(save-excursion (forward-line -1)(current-indentation))

should deliver a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the case for single semicolon comments from `lisp-indent-line` it will behave as you want to.

I have removed it in the code below, you can add this to your emacs config:

```
(defun lisp-indent-line (&optional _whole-exp)
  "Indent current line as Lisp code.
With argument, indent any additional lines of the same expression
rigidly along with this one.
Modified to indent single semicolon comments like double semicolon comments"
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((indent (calculate-lisp-indent)) shift-amt
    (pos (- (point-max) (point)))
    (beg (progn (beginning-of-line) (point))))
    (skip-chars-forward " \t")
    (if (or (null indent) (looking-at "\\s<\\s<\\s<"))
    ;; Don't alter indentation of a ;;; comment line
    ;; or a line that starts in a string.
        ;; FIXME: inconsistency: comment-indent moves ;;; to column 0.
    (goto-char (- (point-max) pos))
      (if (listp indent) (setq indent (car indent)))
      (setq shift-amt (- indent (current-column)))
      (if (zerop shift-amt)
      nil
    (delete-region beg (point))
    (indent-to indent))
      ;; If initial point was within line's indentation,
      ;; position after the indentation.  Else stay at same point in text.
      (if (> (- (point-max) pos) (point))
      (goto-char (- (point-max) pos))))))
```